# Enabled fields in the customer account via code

Tags: php, magento

I'm developing a module where it will change the value of the field `Display Date of Birth` and `View CPF/CNPJ` in `Settings>customers>settings>name and address options`.

When this value is set as required, it shows fields in the customer master in "customer / account / create /", for this I use the following code in an installation script, so that when the module is activated it already enable these fields that do not come by default.

Code:

```
$inchooSwitch = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();

$inchooSwitch->saveConfig('customer/address/dob_show', "req", 'default', '');
$inchooSwitch->saveConfig('customer/address/taxvat_show', "req", 'default', '');
```

Code changes successfully, but when I access the page `customer/account/create/` fields do not appear.

Any idea why this happens?

**update**

I used the hint of Himansu, but happens the same as before does not show the fields on the page:

[image: fields]

as you can see not appear on the Birth Date field

**update x2**

yes, it changes value in core_config_data table, but does not show the field on the page, do not understand why it does not show the fields on the page

[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestion of [Himansu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699814/himansu) and changed this:

```
$inchooSwitch = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();

$inchooSwitch->saveConfig('customer/address/dob_show', "req", 'default', '');
$inchooSwitch->saveConfig('customer/address/taxvat_show', "req", 'default', '');
$inchooSwitch->saveConfig('customer/address/gender_show', "req", 'default', '');
```

for this:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/dob_show', 'req');
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/taxvat_show', 'req');
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/gender_show', 'req');
```

then I saw the system.xml they used a backend_model `adminhtml/system_config_backend_customer_show_customer`, which possessed the `_afterSave` function that set the attribute as visible and necessary, so I used:

```
$dobAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'dob');
$dobAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$dobAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$dobAtribute->save();

$taxvatAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'taxvat');
$taxvatAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$taxvatAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$taxvatAtribute->save();

$genderAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'gender');
$genderAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$genderAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$genderAtribute->save();
```

all code:

```
<?php

Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/dob_show', 'req');
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/taxvat_show', 'req');
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/gender_show', 'req');

$dobAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'dob');
$dobAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$dobAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$dobAtribute->save();

$taxvatAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'taxvat');
$taxvatAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$taxvatAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$taxvatAtribute->save();

$genderAtribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer', 'gender');
$genderAtribute->setData('is_required', 1);
$genderAtribute->setData('is_visible', 1);
$genderAtribute->save();
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

Use below code anywhere for chnage config data.

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('YOUR_PATH_HERE', 'YOUR_VALUE_HERE');
```

So change your code as below.

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/dob_show', 'req' );
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('customer/address/taxvat_show', 'req' );
```

Comment: I used your suggestion but the same thing happened before, updated the post with a picture of the page without the field, as you can see not appear on the Birth Date field

Comment: Find value in `core_config_data` table change or not?

Comment: yes, it changes value in core_config_data table, but does not show the field on the page, do not understand why it does not show the fields on the page, i updated the post with a screen print

Comment: So it's problem about your code try this in default magento and clear all Cache.

Comment: applied the default theme and wiped all the cache but did not work, still does not show